# Will Windows transfer the files to the launching machine or not?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, file-transfer, network-traffic

We have a "Server 1" which is located in "Location A".

Next we have "Server 2" and "Server 3" which are located in "Location B".

```
                       "Location B"
                       "Server 2"

"Location A"   
"Server 1" -----> launches file copy between "Server 2" and "Server 3"

                       "Location B"
                       "Server 3"
```

If I launch a file copy action from "Server 1" - "Location A", which copies files from "Server 2" to "Server 3", both at "Location B", will there be network traffic to "Location A" for the files ?

Operating system is W2008 in "Location A", and W2003 in "Location B".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are copying using the Windows Explorer interface then yes. As I understand it, all the files would be copied to Server 1 first.

The best thing to do would be to go on Server 2 or 3 and initialise the file copy from there.

If this is something that is going to be a common thing, lookup DFS Replication.